# Convert a javacv Frame Into Bitmap using AndroidFrameConverter

Tags: android, bitmap, ffmpeg, javacv

I am trying to convert a Frame of size 1280x720 into Bitmap using javacv AndroidFrameConverter and it takes long time to convert. Here is the sample code of converting.

```
FrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(videoUrl);
frame = grabber.grab();
AndroidFrameConverter converter = new AndroidFrameConverter();
Bitmap originalBitmap = converter.convert(frame);
```

is there any other solution which is faster than this?

Comment: Bitmap conversion is heavy task.So it will take time to get converted. The  thing is what operation do you need to do after converting it in bitmap?

Comment: i want to draw some overlays on bitmap after conversion.

Comment: then its good.Javacv provides this facility through FrameFilter in which you can use ffmpeg command to draw an overlay without converting into bitmap.I add sample code for FrameFilter and then you can play with that to achieve desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code and change filter according to your needs.

```
public class FilterAsync extends AsyncTask {

    private FFmpegFrameGrabber VIDEO_GRABBER;
    private FFmpegFrameRecorder videoRecorder;
    private File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/Abc.mp4");
    private Context mContext;
    private FFmpegFrameFilter filter;
    private boolean isTrue = false;
    private ArrayList<String> videoPaths;
    private File myDirectory;


    public FilterAsync(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        VIDEO_GRABBER = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(file);
        myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Folder/");
        if (!myDirectory.exists()) {
            myDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
        videoPaths = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        Frame tempVideoFrame;
        try {
            VIDEO_GRABBER.start();
            initVideoRecorder(myDirectory + "/video" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4");
            filter.start();
            while (VIDEO_GRABBER.grab() != null) {
                tempVideoFrame = VIDEO_GRABBER.grabImage();
                if (tempVideoFrame != null) {
                    filter.push(tempVideoFrame);
                    tempVideoFrame = filter.pull();
                    videoRecorder.record(tempVideoFrame);
                }
            }
            videoRecorder.stop();
            filter.stop();
            videoRecorder.release();
            VIDEO_GRABBER.stop();
            VIDEO_GRABBER.release();
        } catch (FrameGrabber.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FrameRecorder.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FrameFilter.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
    }


    private void initVideoRecorder(String path) {
        try {
            filter = new FFmpegFrameFilter("transpose=clock ,crop=w=640:h=480:x=0:y=0", VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageWidth(), VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageHeight());

            videoRecorder = FFmpegFrameRecorder.createDefault(path, VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageWidth(), VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageHeight());
           videoRecorder.setAudioChannels(VIDEO_GRABBER.getAudioChannels());
            videoRecorder.start();
        } catch (FrameRecorder.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives warnings and exception: No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to bgr24.

Comment: There must be issue at ur side its working perfectly on my side. Show me ur gradle dependencies for javacv

Comment: compile 'org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.1'
    compile 'org.bytedeco:javacv:1.1'
    compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:2.8.1-1.1'
    compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:2.8.1-1.1:android-arm'
    compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:2.8.1-1.1:android-x86'
    compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.0.0-1.1:android-arm'
    compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.0.0-1.1:android-x86'

Comment: compile 'org.bytedeco:javacv:1.1'  why is this line 2 times?

Comment: Also try using these dependencies for javacv instead


`compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.1'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.0.0-1.1', classifier: 'android-arm'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.8.1-1.1', classifier: 'android-arm'`

Comment: your command is working, but i am overlaying watermark on video using this command, "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:main_h-overlay_h-5 [out]" This command gives error, second thing this command is valid when i run through FFMpeg. I have a workaround to overlay using ffmpeg but it is slow. It takes 2 min to overlay a static png to video of 15 sec. Have you any suggestions?

Comment: yes. It will give error because its not a filter.Javacv currently supports FFmpeg filters only and if you search overlay filter then it will be helpful to you

Comment: if it has helped you then i think you should upvote the answer :)

Comment: Can I set the image marker to the bitmap using this comand?
I am using the same thing but when I use "ImageOverlaybitmap" all works but processing speed moves to 12min for 1min video

Answer (score 2):

`Frame` returned by `FrameGrabber.grab()` is javacv specific, `Bitmap` is Android specific, I doubt there is a faster convertion method between the two because they don't know each other and both being optimized for their own use they cannot optimize a conversion process between both data formats.

You are moving 1280 * 720 * 4 Bytes, roughly 3.6 MB per frame, it's a lot for mobile devices, above all taking into account memory allocation.

I doubt you'll find another conversion tool without exchanging javacv for something else - can't imagine a tool made specifically to convert javacv's `Frame` to Android `Bitmap` to replace the built-in methods.

Besides, `AndroidFrameConverter.convert()` is already pretty clever - it creates the `Bitmap` only for the first time or if the specification has changed (like size etc.), then just copies the bytes.

So luckily it has the ability to reuse once created `Bitmap` instance, `FFmpegFrameGrabber` has also this ability, so on the first run they will create each an appropriate object but from the second frame on should reuse the objects they have - this way at least no unnecessary memory allocation will happen, which kills performance on mobile devices. That means that converting many frames on the average should be way faster than converting only one frame - just don't create new instances of the grabber and converter for each frame.

Parallelizing using GPU might be possible - create a `Bitmap` manually, partition `Frame`'s Buffer and set pixels of the `Bitmap` in parallel. I've never done something like that myself so can't really comment more. Just keep in mind that parallel algorithms have their own overhead and are not always faster than sequential ones. And I'm not sure how portable GPU programming is. Parallelizing using CPU shouldn't be worth trying - how many cores do have current devices? 4? The overhead should be more than the gain.